# re-arrange Legend in plotly boxplot

Tags: r, shiny, legend, plotly

I have been struggling for re-arrenging the legend in one of my plots. The example below ilustrates the problem I am currently having:

```
library(plotly)
library(data.table)

test <- data.table(NAME = c(rep(x = "b",10),rep(x = "c",10),rep(x = "a",10)), VALUE = sample(0:100,30, replace = T)/100)

plot_ly(test, x = ~NAME, y = ~VALUE, color = ~NAME, type = "box")
```

So, when I run the function what I am getting is a plot with a legend ordered alphabetically ("a","b","c") and the boxplots ordered (from left to right) accordingly to the legend. What I am trying to get is a plot with a legend which follows the same order than in the dataset ("b","c","a") and the boxplots ordered accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how to do that with Plotly, but a workaround is to replace characters  by factors in the `data.frame` and order them as in the dataset:

```
test$NAME <- factor(test$NAME, levels=unique(test$NAME))
plot_ly(test, x = ~NAME, y = ~VALUE, color = ~NAME, type = "box")
```

[image]